# XML Serialization – serialize the properties in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, serialization, user-controls

How to serialize the properties in user control?

I have tried the following code but I got InvalidOperationExceptio, While creating the XmlSerializer object

```
MyUserControl userControl = new MyUserControl();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyUserControl));
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
serializer.Serialize(writer, userControl);
```

**Exception:**

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled

HResult=-2146233079

Message=There was an error reflecting type 'Demo.MyUserControl'.

Comment: For a similar problem, I data bound my control to a class and then serialized that, are you talking about data binding attributes such as the user controls name or custom properties/values?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27158/XamlWriter-and-Bindings-Serialization

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it like this IMHO.

You should write a separate "Data Transfer Object (DTO)" style class to hold the data that you want to serialize, and use *that* instead. (You'd need to write Transform methods to convert the data back and forth of course.)

Otherwise you will couple your data storage format tightly to your user control.

If you use a separate class for serializing, it will make it much more manageable and flexible especially if you need to add new properties in the future.

If you really *must* serialize the user control (and I highly recommend that you *don't*) you could try using [DataContract serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms733127.aspx) which has an "opt-in" mechanism for which properties get serialized, rather than the "opt-out" mechanism for the older serialization.

Comment: DataContract serialization doesn't solve the problem as UserControl is neither marked as Serializable or DataContract, so any derived type cannot be serialized with DataContractSerializer.